# Django_Facebook admin login

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-facebook

I'm using django_facebook[1] but when I use FacebookCustomUser and run ./manage.py syncdb it doens't generate admin user. How can I proceed?

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_facebook.FacebookCustomUser'

*[1]https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/*

Comment: Have you add it into `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py?

Comment: Yes. Just the auth_user are not being generated, take a look pls: https://dpaste.de/GsOk

Comment: My problem is, how can we login on admin after install django_facebook? Which user I have to use to /admin/ ?